# How to echo same sentence random times in php?

Tags: php

I need to implement this method to my webpage. I want to echo the same sentence random times every time someone refresh my php webpage.

For example: Hello World!

Comment: What do you mean by "*random times*"? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: For example, I want to display the sentence: 'Hello World' a random times between 1 and 500 times every time you refresh the page. I have tried: $randomThings = array('Hello World!');
    echo $randomThings[mt_rand(0,count($randomThings)-1)];

Comment: @Erik Eldagsen Marquez  What have you tried ? Stack Overflow is not a free coding service.try to  Search and research and try writing some code. 
If you then have trouble, you can come back here and ask a proper question, providing [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
<?php
$min = 1; // Minimum 1 time
$max = 10; // Maximum 10 times
$string = "Hello world!\n"; // Print Hello World! and a new line
$x = rand($min,$max); // Make the random
$i = 0; // Set the iterator
do {
  echo $string; // Echo the text
  $i = $i + 1; // Increment the iterator
} while ($i < $x); // Test to make sure we didn't do it too many times
?>
```

This `echo`s "Hello world!" anywhere from 1 to 10 times. You can search the PHP API to see how this works.

Comment: It works! I did echo htmlentities($x['_message']); to display the sentence Thank you very much, this helped me a lot!

Comment: @Erik No problem, happy to help :)